# Javascript XSLT transformation omits the xml declaration

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, browser

It seems like all browsers except IE omit the xml declaration when doing XSLT transformations in Javascript - even the stylesheet specifies in the output tag that the xml declaration should not be omitted.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Why is the declaration relevant to you?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a test case that outputs an XML declaration for me with Firefox:

```js
var xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString('<root>foo</root>', 'application/xml');

var xslDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString([
  '<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">',
  '<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>',
  '<xsl:template match="/"><xsl:copy-of select="."/></xsl:template>',
  '</xsl:stylesheet>'].join('\n'), 'application/xml');

var xsltProc = new XSLTProcessor();
xsltProc.importStylesheet(xslDoc);

var resultDoc = xsltProc.transformToDocument(xmlDoc);

var serializedXml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(resultDoc);
console.log(serializedXml);

var pre = document.createElement('pre');
pre.textContent = serializedXml;
document.body.appendChild(pre);
```